# Bidirectional ClientServer Communication in java

Tags: java

Is it possible to simultaneously read and write from a socket?I tried bidirectional client server communication...But the thing is first i sent the file(bytes) from client to server received successfully.but when i am response back to the file to server the broken pipe error(socket exception was occurred)

Comment: That probably means the server closed the socket and never tried to read your response.

Comment: Please share me  how to rectify that problem...i am facing the problem from past two months..

Comment: Do you get the "broken pipe" error on the server or the client? What happens on the other one?

Comment: Yup...i got broken pipe error on server side.On the other side no error was occurred but the received response file (server to client)size as 0bytes

Comment: Please help me how to rectify the long problem

Comment: people may be able to help you better if you just shared your client and server code rather than just mentioning what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

A socket *is* a bidirectional channel. That's why you have an input and an output stream on each end.

If you get a broken pipe exception, it means that one of the two sides (the client or the server) prematurely closed the streams. So it depends who is complaining. If it's the server (sounds like it from your question), then it means the client wrote its message and then closed everything on its side. So when the server tries to respond, it's not there. So check the client.

To help you, here is a very basic client/server implementation example:

[Server](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/84network/EchoServer.java.html)

[Client](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/84network/EchoClient.java.html)

Notice how the client never closes anything until it's ready to leave the `while` loop and terminate its execution completely. It sounds like it is your problem. If after this line `out.println("[" + screenName + "]: " + s);`, you add a `out.close();`, you will likely get that same exception you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to simultaneously read and write from a socket?

No, it's not possible to do it "simultaneously" with the same socket.  To do it simultaneously al parts needs to act as client and servers at same time with a listener socket on each one.

But reading your question probably you require a common client<->server comunication when client sends a request and server responds in the same socket, and this is possible with one socket.

---

<strike>To be more precise with the response is required to be more precise with the problem.</strike>

As you say your comment there is different problems that could affect. One group about the network infraestructure other about programatic concepts and another about memory sizing

1. About the infraestructure be sure that your server could see correctly your client. If you are in a local network probably there is no problem but if the server is in another network or over internet probably problems with gateways, routing, firewalls,... could cause the server could not locate the client back.
2. About programatic as i say before you are using only one java socket. This could not perform "simultaneously" the informations transfer there is only one channel (but the magic of java makes that appears a real parallel communication) . Java encapsulates this in two streams "InputStream" and "OutputStream" that appears to be "parallel" but not. There are over the same I/O and you need to be carefully to dont close the output stream to the server. The process mus be :

> send stream -> wait respose -> receive stream -> close streams

3. Finally if you are sending files probably you are storing in the server all data to memory before dump it. Is the file a big file? If yes probably a server or client out of memory allocating the data to be interchanged could case a broken pipe hidden the real out of memory. On this case try increasing the heap memory used by your server or testing before with small files (few kb).

Comment: You *can* simultaneously send data in both directions over the same socket (well, pair of sockets, since the server and client have one each).

Comment: I have kept both the server and client codes...and i need to send the file from client to sever then server will receive the file response back to client.Now i could performed one way(client to server was well)but when i am try to response back to client broken pipe exception was occurred...trying a lot of methods and many of the tutorials but not at all give better solution..  :-(

Answer (score 0):

You neither close the socket nor the outputstream. You do a shutdownOutput() in the client side.Use outputstream.shutdownOutput(); code this line after send function in client side.Refer[This is half closed socket function for bidirectional communication](http://chihuosvip.com/questions/2076321/send-and-receive-over-the-same-socket)